# Not able to launch DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan with Gremlin Server on Amazon EC2 by using a AWS CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, titan

I am trying to configure DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan with Gremlin Server on Amazon EC2 by using a AWS CloudFormation template, by following the link [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.GremlinServerEC2.html)

Under `Prerequisites` its mentioned that we need `gremlin-server and dynamodb.properties` files.

Q1. I have got the files from github [link](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend). Are these the correct files and i can use as is OR do i need to modify the contents of these files ?

Q2. On using these files as is,  i am able to create CloudFormation stack which creates a EC2 instance but i am not able to SSH to this EC2 instance . Also it is not creating a gremlin server and no tables in DynamoDB, but as per the documentation it should. I am not getting what i am doing wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the [new CloudFormation template](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/janusgraph/dynamodb-janusgraph-storage-backend-cfn.yaml) available on the [JanusGraph branch](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/tree/janusgraph). I tested it yesterday and it appears to work.